# Jquery IdleTimeOut Plugin intergration error

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image][image][image][image]I am trying to use jquery-Idletimeout plugin for auto logout across tabs and windows. But I am getting error as :

```
Uncaught TypeError: e(...).dialog is not a function
```

I have included the following versions of jquery,jquery ui ,store.js,jquery idletimeout.min.js:

```
<script src="{% static 'dev/others/jquery-2.2.4.min.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="{% static 'vendors/storejs/dist/store.everything.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'vendors/idletimeout_plugin/jquery-idleTimeout.min.js' %}"></script>
```

In my js file, I have included the script as :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).idleTimeout({
    redirectUrl: 'https://github.com/JillElaine/jquery-idleTimeout', // redirect to this url
    idleTimeLimit: 15, // 15 seconds
    activityEvents: 'click keypress scroll wheel mousewheel', // separate each event with a space
    dialogDisplayLimit: 30, // Time to display the warning dialog before logout (and optional callback) in seconds
    sessionKeepAliveTimer: false // Set to false to disable pings.
  });
});
```

I have provided the screenshots of my network tab as well.

But I am getting the above error as explained.

Any suggestions for debugging this error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your jquery files you are calling in the below parts are not getting loaded. Please can you open network  tool in chrome and give me snap shot of js tab.

```
<script src="{% static 'dev/others/jquery-2.2.4.min.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="{% static 'vendors/storejs/dist/store.everything.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'vendors/idletimeout_plugin/jquery-idleTimeout.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: are you able to see the files loading jquery-idleTimeout.min.js store.everything.min.js or are they marked in read in your network tab

Comment: I see them loading but I dont see jquery Ui script loading.

Comment: jquery-ui.min.js ?

Comment: yes.jquery-ui.min.js, i dont see anywhere loading in network tab after using the cdn link as well .

Comment: can you share your code snippet without server syntax. I will be able to debug better or put it in a fiddle

Comment: I have already provided the code, which i am using other than this codes are application specific so I cant share them